# Qt 4.8 signalMapper signal and slot

Tags: c++, qt

I have been trying to use QSignalMapper with Qt 4.8. But I have not been able to get signal from the signalmapper. My code is similar with what qt has on their website. my mySlot function should receive value and execute, But nothing happens with button clicked.

```
vector<QPushButton *> button;
QSignalMapper *signalMapper;
signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{ 
    button.push_back(new QPushButton(“myButton”);
    QObject::connect(button[i], SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map())); 
    signalMapper->setMapping(button[i], i);
}
QObject::connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(mySlot(int)));

void class::mySlot(int position)
{ 
   QMessageBox msgBox;
   msgBox.setText(QString(“Button #: %1”).arg(position));
   msgBox.exec();
}
```

Comment: Is there a header defining `mySlot()`?  It's just a guess, but you may mean to declare it as `void mySlot(int position)`.

Comment: does your vector of buttons go out of scope?  That would disconnect the slots.  Have you tried QVector?